AB-test percentiles difference
I have two groups in AB-test, where I am measuring start of program running.
Since I have both A and B large observation samples, I put data randomly into N buckets. Inside each bucket I calculate percentiles. Now I have new samples with N observations and I can compare them using t-test.
After comparing I got unexpected results: 50 and 95 percentiles observation samples give p-value lower than 0.05, so these groups have difference. But by 75 percentile these samples have no difference with p-value = 0.2. How could it happen?

There isn't quite enough information in your question to say just what's going on. Relying solely on p-values for this type of comparison can be misleading, and t-tests performed in the way that you have done might not be appropriate, depending on the nature of your data. Please edit the question to show some of the results you found (actual differences and standard errors, not just p-values) and a plot of the empirical cumulative distribution function of your outcome values for (samples from) groups A and B. That should help clarify the situation.

There is nothing odd about this. I can easily imagine A's median being > B's median, but  then B's 95th percentile being > A's 95th percentile (because B has a heavy tail), but in between (at the 75th percentile), they are close (the CDF's cross). You really should plot the eCDF of the 2 samples; the reason probably will "hit you between the eyes"; this is my favorite statistical test, the IOTT (or "inter ocular traumatic test").
